# Why would a command called from system() wait to execute?

Tags: c, linux, cgi, system, sleep

Working on an embedded system, running customized stripped down version of `Linux 2.6.39.4`, with a web page front end using `javascript` code to communicate with a back end coded in `C` via `CGI` scripts. (Inherited this project, its a nightmare)

**The Situation:** A web page calls a `cgi` script, which in turn fires up some `C` code, which makes a few `system()` calls, and then sleeps waiting for data. For reference, this particular section of code is initializing a WLAN module.

**The Issue:** At the beginning of the `C` code, a `system()` call is made to start the `udhcpc` process. After the calling function exists, it calls a second function which calls `sleep()` to wait for data. However, it appears that the `udhcpc` process started prior does not execute until after the `sleep`. I am lost.

The specific `system` command being executed is:

```
system("udhcpc -n -i eth1 -q");
```

I was under the impression that a system call should wait there until the command finishes, at which point it exits and continues on. In my terminal window, I do not see the exepcted output from `udhcpc` until **after** my sleep executes (known from logging some debug statements to follow execution path)

Am I misunderstanding how the `system` call works? Or does this have anything to do with the fact that its a `C` module being executed via `CGI`?

For clarify, this is what the order of operations currently:

1. Button is clicked on web page, which calls CGI script
2. CGI script calls into compiled C application
3. C application uses system call to start udhcpc
4. ----> I would expect to see output from udhcpc in terminal here
5. C application sleeps and waits for data
6. ----> Output from udhcpc is not seen until now, after sleep finishes

Comment: Does adding the `-f` option help?

Comment: @IanAbbott no.. still the same thing. The behavior makes it seem like the `system()` call completes, the calling function exits, but any processing of the command passed to the `system` call is not executed until later, which makes no sense to me

Comment: If it's a CGI, how does output appear in the terminal? Or did you mean that it appears in the browser?

Comment: Terminal is hooked up to the device via serial line, CGI script is executed from the web browser and launches a pre-compiled C application (all of these things are on the target device's file system), which is where the `system()` call is executed

Comment: Do you have a shell that you can launch your application from manually? It might be easier to see what is going on that way. I think @rici's point is that the CGI process launched from a web server probably does not have a controlling TTY to send its output to.

Comment: Yeah I can execute the app via terminal, anything specific I should be checking for? Or do you just mean to execute it from the terminal and see if the results differ?

Comment: Note that `system` doesn't run your command directly - it runs a shell that parses the parameter and runs the command. Perhaps the shell is waiting for something. Using `fork` and `exec` directly would avoid the shell.